# Object doesn't support set_viewXML

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am using SharePoint 2013 and attempting to filter a list by a Lookup choice field.

After searching around and attempting a variety of ways of inserting the query XML, I have the following code:

```
function getListItems(listName, viewTitle){
    var myClientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var oWebsite = myClientContext.get_web();
    var oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle(listName);

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    var q = '<View><Query><Where>' +
        '<Eq>' +
          '<FieldRef Name="SignLocationsList" LookupId="true" />' +
          '<Value Type="Lookup">HQ</Value>' +
        '</Eq>' +
        '</Where></Query></View>';
    camlQuery.set_viewXML(q);

    // No specific query at this time
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery); 

    myClientContext.load(collListItem,'Include(Id,Title,Posting_x0020_Date_x0020_Planned,Removal_x0020_Date_x0020_Planned,SignRemoved,AttachmentFiles,SignLocationsList');
    myClientContext.executeQueryAsync(getItemsSuccess, getItemsFail);
}
```

However, I still end up with the error :

> Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'set_viewXML'

Without adding the query portion, I am able to see the entire list and display it the way that I need to.  It is only when attempting to add the query XML that I end up with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurs since [SP.CamlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff407790(v=office.14).aspx) object contains [SP.CamlQuery.set_viewXml method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee549968%28v=office.14%29.aspx) but not the `set_viewXML`.

Replace the line:

```
camlQuery.set_viewXML(q);
```

with:

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml(q);
```

Comment: Ugh... must have been looking at that so long that my eyes gave up on the case sensitive portion.  Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, first of all i tried to verify the most common issue: missing View root element, but this time everything was correct and only after that this case sensitive typo was found ;)